# Csv file character conversion in python to Japanese language

Tags: python, package, decode, encode, cjk

I am having a csv file which contains columns having numbers and some strings but there are few rows having characters like this ->"
ã¥ûzF¤i
ãAz¿AMtgï¿ÆµÄwüÒ©ç¥ûµ½
ã"
When i open this via tables or notepad++ with conversion to utc-8-bom all the above characters are converted to japenese.
How can we achieve this via python code.
As of now i am trying to open file and read it like this.
Is there different way to encode or decode these characters?
with open(file_path, 'r') as output_file:
for line in output_file:
print(line)

Comment: `open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")`

Comment: It is giving this @tripleee
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 8: invalid start byte

Comment: Then Notepad is lying when it says it's UTF-8 with a BOM. Try `encoding="utf-8"` (probably won't work either) and/or see my answer to the second duplicate for more in-depth troubleshooting background. In the worst case, you have a file with mixed encodings. See also the  [Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/character-encoding/info)